# Run flask App using Spark-Submit

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pyspark

I am building an API using Flask that requires some Spark context. Is this good way to run Flask application using **Spark-Submit for Long run** instead python command??

Comment: You can use `celery`

Comment: Can u give me any git link that integrates flask Spark and Celery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Celery` : [Link to docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html)

This is an example post calling Async Jobs on spark in a web application. Check [Spark+Celery blog](https://qbox.io/blog/asynchronous-apache-spark-flask-celery-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 0):

You can run it using `python` command with [findspark](https://pypi.org/project/findspark/) inside your code.

`app.py`:

```
# some imports

import findspark
findspark.init()

# spark imports and routes
```